# [Xamarin]style, Theme.Holo & Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

I make app with tabbed page.

If i use AppCompat, I can't customize tab, but I can use
moving tab with swipe action.

If i use Holo, I can customize tab, but I can't use
moving tab with swipe action.

***My Holo Theme***

```
      <resources>
        <!--my custom theme-->
        <style name="MyTheme"
                 parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
          <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
          <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>    
        </style>

        <!--tab text style-->
        <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
               parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
          <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
          <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_selector</item>    
        </style>


        <!--tab style-->
        <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
          <!--<item name="android:background">#DCEBF0</item>-->
          <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_selector</item>
          <item name="android:layout_width">1dp</item>  
        </style>
      </resources>
```

***my AppCompat Theme***

```
      <resources>
          <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
          </style>
          <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
          <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
              <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
              <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
              <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
              <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
              <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->


          <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
               colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
              <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>    
          </style>


      </resources>
```

how can i customize tab and using swipe action?

or can I change only tab theme to Holo in AppCompat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Appcompat, you can still do it programmatically:

Use this code in your OnCreate overwrite method (activity you want to show the tabs):

```
    //Setting TabLayout
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Setting viewPager
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new 
                              PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
                              tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
                   TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

and create a class to you page adapter like this:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
   int mNumOfTabs;

   private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"TAB1", "TAB2", "TAB3"};


   public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
      super(fm);
      this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
   }

   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return tabTitles[position];
   }

   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

This is how you define a ViewPager in your xml layout file:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
     android:background="@drawable/gradient_grey">
```

Let me know if it works for you!